# error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named 'StoreDb'. Line 9 Position 94

Tags: c#, wpf

I download the source code of book from github [here](https://github.com/Apress/pro-wpf-4.5-in-csharp).

I am building DataBinding project in chapter 19 but it doesn't build and I get this compilation error.

> error MC3066: The type reference cannot find a public type named
>   'StoreDb'. Line 9 Position 94.

```
<Window x:Class="DataBinding.BindToObjectDataProvider"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="BindToObjectDataProvider" Height="450" Width="400"
    xmlns:data="clr-namespace:StoreDatabase;assembly=StoreDatabase" 
    >
  <Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider ObjectType="{x:Type data:StoreDb}"                         
                       MethodName="GetProductsSlow" x:Key="products" IsAsynchronous="True"></ObjectDataProvider>
  </Window.Resources>
```

Can anyone see why it doesn't build? Thank you!

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Make sure your WPF project reference the "StoreDatabase" assembly correctly. In the assembly, there should be a StoreDatabase namespace, which contians the StoreDb class.

Comment: @YantingChen I did add StoreDatabase.dll to references but that didn't help. I went to references, browsed for the dll and added it and checked. Do we need anything else to add it?

Answer (score 0):

I had copied the chapter 19 folder (where the project was) to another folder to build/run/play with so I don't modify the original but it required StoreDatabase project which was in root folder.

I tried to build the project on another PC that gave me a clue, it had an error that one project was not loaded. Copied that project to root fixed it.

This was the error loading solution.

> C:\Projects\StoreDatabase\StoreDatabase.csproj : error  : The project
>   file could not be loaded. Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Projects\StoreDatabase\StoreDatabase.csproj'. 
>   C:\Projects\StoreDatabase\StoreDatabase.csproj